# How to improve performance of charAt with BigIntegers?

Tags: java, string, performance, biginteger

#### Input:

> T (number of inputs)
>   T number of integers (range 1 < n < 1000000000)

#### Output:

> Number of trailing zero's in the factorial of the given numbers.

#### My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class fact1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long t1, t2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb;
        int T = 0, i = 0, len = 0;
        BigInteger count = BigInteger.ZERO;
        T = sc.nextInt();
        String[] c = new String[T];
        BigInteger[] b = new BigInteger[T];
        BigInteger[] result = new BigInteger[T];
        for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
            c[i]=sc.next();
        for(i = 0; i < T; i++)
            b[i]=new BigInteger(c[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            result[i] = BigInteger.ONE;
            while( !b[i].equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                result[i] = result[i].multiply(b[i]);
                b[i] = b[i].subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }
        t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for(i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            len = result[i].toString().length() - 1;
            sb = new StringBuilder(result[i].toString());
            while(len >= 0) {
                if(sb.toString().charAt(len) == '0') {
                    count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                    len--;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(count);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    t2=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(t2-t1);
    }
```

#### Sample input/output:

> Input
>       2 (T)
>
> 10 c[0]
>   100 c[1]
>
> Output:
>   2
>   26

It works perfectly but the problem being it's very slow and I need to improve the speed drastically and for like 1 million inputs it takes like 40 seconds to execute. My guess is the conversion of `BigInteger` to `String` and `charAt()` operation are the culprits. Is there any way to improve the performance?

**Update:**

I changed my code according to Peter Lawrey's suggestion and it works like a charm and I can't measure the time taken in seconds and ended up changing to nano Seconds.

**My edited code is:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fact2
{
 public static void main(String args[])
{

 int T=0,i=0,count=0,result=0,k=0;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 T=sc.nextInt();
 int n[]=new int[T];
 for(i=0;i<T;i++)
 n[i]=sc.nextInt();
 long t1=System.nanoTime();
 for(i=0;i<T;i++)
  {
   result=1;
   k=1;
   count=0;

    while(k>0)
     {
        result=result*5;
        k=n[i]/result;
        count=count+k;


     }
   System.out.println(count);

}
long t2=System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2-t1);



}

}
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly? It's very hard to read and understand with the inconsistent indentation and random blank lines thrown in all over the place.

Comment: Why do you create a StringBuilder with the results of converting the BigInteger to a String and then, every time you want to check one of the characters, convert the StringBuilder to a String? This makes no sense.

Comment: According to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000000%21 1000000000! is something about 10^8565705523. 

Comparing to 10^80 which is the number of atoms in the universe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) This is a **pretty big number**.

But the good part is: if converting to string and using ascii you could fit 8'565'705'523 digits in just about 8 gig of ram.

The bad part: This is definively a perfomance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calculating the number, you could just calculate the number of trailing zeros which is much faster.  For each 5, you will get a zero

```
// completes in O(ln N) time.
public static void main(String args[])  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Factorial of which number: ");
    long num = sc.nextLong();
    long zeros = 0;
    do {
        num /= 5;
        zeros += num;
    } while(num > 0);
    System.out.println("The number of trailing zero is " + zeros);
}
```

If you are looking for the number of trailing zeros for the *product of a sequence of numbers* calculate the number of factors or 2 and 5.  The number of zeros will be the minimum of these two.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    int twos = 0, fives = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextLong()) {
        long n = in.nextLong();
        twos += factorsOf(n, 2);
        fives += factorsOf(n, 5);
    }
    System.out.printf("The product has %,d trailing zeros%n", Math.min(twos, fives));
}

public static int factorsOf(long n, int divisor) {
    int count = 0;
    while(n % divisor == 0) {
        n /= divisor;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You get a zero for each 5, plus another zero for each 25, plus another zero for each 125, plus another zero for each 3125, ...

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you, however I suspect the OP want the product of some numbers. I guess you meant to include 625.

Comment: Oops, you're quite correct. I skipped 625. The OP did mention factorial, but in any case, pointing out the relationship to the prime factors 2 and 5, and 5 being the "limiting reagent", is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh man that's interesting never thought of that and definitely I guess the performance will improve :)

Comment: @user1613360  The trick to remember is that most of these sort of puzzles are mathematical in nature rather than plan programming tasks.  Find a mathematical transformation which is cheaper and you will be dramatically faster.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting to string you can do some basic math:

Trailing digit = number *mod* 10

To remove last digit: shorterDigit = number/10.

You can do both operations with `divideAndRemainder` function.

So your code could look something like

```
BigInt result = ...;
while (result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)>0) {
   BigInteger[] d = result.divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
   if (d[1].compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
     ++count;
   } else {
     break;
   }
   result = d[0];
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the speed didn't improve much and moreover I think doing n mod 10 and n/10 for each input is a bit costly.

Answer (score 1):

`factorial(n) = 1 * 2 * 3 * ...... * n` then surely every time you multiply by a multiple of `5` you will see a zero because you've also multiplied by at least one `2` already. In fact you can ignore the `2`a as there are so many more of them than `5`s. Thus `4! = 24` and `5! = 120` and `9! = 362880` while `10! = 3628800`.

So surely to get the number of zeros at the end of `n!` we just need to work out how many times we need to multiply by `5`.

So it might be as simple as:

```
return n / 5;
```

This looks like it should work in my test spreadsheet ... hang on - no it doesn't! It breaks around `26`.

I was nearly right but I missed some further factors - like when 5 * 5 = 25 is multiplied.

Here's the final code:

```
public long trailingZerosInFactorial(long n) {
    int zeros = 0;
    for (long t = 5; t < n; t *= 5) {
        zeros += n / t;
    }
    return zeros;
}
```

And have a look at [Factorials and Trailing Zeroes](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm) on [PurpleMath](http://www.purplemath.com/index.htm) for some further support of my theory.